# Restriction on child pointer of a restricted pointer?

Tags: c, gcc, c99, restrict-qualifier

The [article](https://cellperformance.beyond3d.com/articles/2006/05/demystifying-the-restrict-keyword.html) mentions:

> Restricted pointers can be copied from one to another to create a hierarchy of pointers. However there is one limitation defined in the C99 standard. The child pointer must not be in the same block-level scope as the parent pointer. The result of copying restricted pointers in the same block-level scope is undefined.

And then it provides an example:

```
{
  vector3* restrict position   = &obj_a->position;
  float*   restrict position_x = &position->x; <-- UNDEFINED
  {
    float* restrict position_y = &position->y; <-- VALID
  }
}
```

Tho, later on, it has another example:

```
void
move( vector3* restrict velocity, 
      vector3* restrict position, 
      vector3* restrict acceleration, 
      float             time_step,  
      size_t            count, 
      size_t            stride )
{
  float* restrict acceleration_x = &acceleration->x;
  float* restrict velocity_x     = &velocity->x;
  float* restrict position_x     = &position->x;
```

I thought now the restricted parent pointer `position` is in the same scope as its child pointer  `position_x`, no?  Isn't it not allowed according to the paragraph I quoted at the beginning of this post?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, the authors of the Standard started by deciding what optimizations they wanted `restrict` to facilitate, and then tried to write rules that would classify as Undefined Behavior all situations where those optimizations would be observable. 
 Unfortunately, the rules as written end up being much more complicated than a description of the allowable optimizations would be, while simultaneously failing to handle corner cases in reasonable--or even meaningful fashion.  For example, the way the Standard defines "based upon", the expression `(p1 == p2) ? p3 : p4` would be "based upon" `p1` if `p1==p2` and `p3!=p4`, since replacing `p1` with a pointer to identical data would change the value of the expression.  Somewhat more bizarrely, the Standard may be interpreted (and clang and gcc interpret it this way!) as saying that the lvalue expression `p[1]` isn't always based upon `p`.

If instead of looking at what programs are "allowed" to do, one were to describe the implementations of `restrict` in terms of sequencing, that would simplify things. Operations using lvalues which are at least potentially derived from a `restrict`-qualified pointer and occur within its lifetime are sequenced with regard to each other and the beginning and end of that lifetime, and operations in its lifetime that occur using lvalues which might not be derived from it are sequenced with regard to each other and with regard to the beginning and end of that lifetime, but operations in the two groups may be arbitrarily interleaved.  If two pointers are declared in the same block, the ends of their lifetimes are not sequenced, then a compiler given:

```
void test(int *p)
{
  int * restrict p1 = p;
  *p1 = 1;
  int * restrict p2 = p1;
  *p2 = 2;
}
```

could transform it into:

```
void test(int *p)
{
  // Start lifetime of p1
  int p1_temp = *p; // Copy everything that will be accessed via p1
  int * restrict p1 = &p1_temp;

  *p1 = 1;

  // Start lifetime of p2
  int p2_temp = *p1; // Copy everything that will be accessed via p2
  int * restrict p2 = &p2_temp;

  *p2 = 2;

  // End lifetime of p2
  *p1 = p2_temp; // Copy data back to *p1

  // End lifetime of p1
  *p = p1_temp; // Copy data back to *p
}
```

which would work, but because the ending of the lifetimes of p1 and p2 are not sequenced, the last two statements could be transposed, breaking the code.

I think the intention of the Standard here is that the lifetime of a function's arguments extend past the lifetime of any other automatic objects, effectively behaving as though such objects are within a nested block.  Given that clang and gcc seem to try to exploit some of the nonsensical corner cases of the Standard's definition of "restrict", however, it would be dangerous to expect them to behave sensibly in cases where the Standard is even remotely ambiguous.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your thought.  I think your example has undefined behavior because `int * restrict p1` and `int * restrict p2` means that they are not aliased to any integer.  Hence, it means p1, p2 and p can't be pointed to the same memory location.  No?

Comment: @HCSF: What is necessary is that within the lifetime of `p2`, the set of things accessed by it or pointers based upon it is disjoint from the set of things accessed via other ways.  If `p2` were within an inner block, there would be no problem.  I don't think there should have been any problem with having the Standard accommodate the above construct by saying that objects' lifetime ends in the opposite order of declaration, and that active restrictions start when a `restrict`-qualified pointer first gets a value, but the "formal" definition of `restrict` is rather sloppy, and this...

Comment: ...issue is minor compared to its other problems, such as the fact that the lvalue `p[1]` isn't always based upon `p`.